# Sets relations and functions : FIND RANGE

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $\displaystyle f = \{(x , \left( \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2} \right)) : x\in \Bbb R\}$ be a function. Determine the range of $f$.

I did it like this:
**Domain**: Since denominator can't be equal to zero, $1 + x^2 \neq 0 \Longrightarrow x^2 \neq -1$.

**Range**: Let $y= f(x)$

$\displaystyle y = \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}\Longrightarrow x = \sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}}$

$1-y \neq 0 \Longrightarrow y\neq 1$

But the correct answer given is **range** is any **positive real number x such that $0 \le x < 1$**

Comment: I edited your question in $\LaTeX$. Please check that I didn't alter the content of your question.

Comment: Note that *let $f$ be a function* is weird because by the definition of $f$ it is indeed a function.

Comment: okay ignore it and thanks for editing

Comment: edited. there is no problem now

Answer (score 2):

A typical way to find the range of a real function of real variable is to try to compute it's inverse and see what problems you run into and what you get.

What you wrote in your question skips the bit where you've made a mistake.

Let's try to compute the inverse of $f$:

Let $y\in \Bbb R$. Suppose $\displaystyle y=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$, for some $x\in \operatorname{dom}(f)=\Bbb R$, (which is equivalent to assuming $y\in \operatorname{Ran}(f))$. (This already tells you that $0\leq y< 1$, but ignore it for now).

$\begin{align}
 y=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} &\Longrightarrow &y(1+x^2)=x^2 &\\
 &\Longrightarrow &y=x^2(1-y) &\\
 &\Longrightarrow &x^2=\frac{y}{1-y} &\,(\text{if } y\neq 1)\\
 &\Longrightarrow &x=\sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}} &(\text{if } \frac{y}{1-y}\ge 0)
\end{align}$

So we see there are some problems with $y= 1$ and $\displaystyle \frac{y}{1-y}< 0$.

We analyze this cases separately:

If $y=1$, then $\displaystyle 1=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ and it's easy to get a contradiction.

If $\displaystyle \frac{y}{1-y}< 0$ check @Babak. S 's answer to conclude that $\displaystyle \frac{y}{1-y}\ge 0 \iff 0\leq y<1$  and get another contradiction.

Therefore $y\neq 1$ and $0\leq y<1$ which is equivalent to $0\leq y<1$.

After all this you should prove that $\operatorname{Ran}(f)=[0,1[$ by proving the double inclusion $\operatorname{Ran}(f)\subseteq [0,1[$ and $\operatorname{Ran}(f)\supseteq [0,1[$.

Comment: +10 fo your nice survey. Thanks for the reference to my small poor hint. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that :

When $y<0$ then $1-y>0$ and so $y/(1-y)<0$.

When $0\leq y< 1$ then $1-y>0$ again and so $y/(1-y)\geq0$.

When $y>1 $ then $1-y<0$ and so again $y/(1-y)\leq0$.

And clearly the function under root square is not defined at $y=1$, so it is excluded from our range.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle f(x) = \left( \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2} \right)$

Adding and subtracting 1 from the numerator

$\displaystyle f(x) = \left( \frac{x^2 + 1 - 1}{1 + x^2} \right)$

$\displaystyle f(x) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \right)$

Now, we know that min value of $x^2$ is 0.

Putting min value of x in the function.

$\displaystyle f(0) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1 + 0^2} \right) = 0$

Hence, min value of the function is 0.

Now, max value of $x^2$ is $\infty$.

$\displaystyle f(\infty) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1 + \infty^2} \right)$

As 1 is negligibly small when compared to $\infty$, it can be neglected from the denominator. Also, we know $1/\infty$ equals 0. Hence max value of the function is approximately:

$\displaystyle f(\infty) = 1$

There you go range = [0, 1)